# Why is my <table> data overflowing out of its parent's <div> bootstrap container?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Trying to use angular with bootstrap to display my data. I have mock data contained in a component and being displayed in the component's html file. I don't know why when the table got bigger, it's not pushing (being responsive to) the parent's content down instead it went beyond the container and exceeded the footer component.

This is my `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title here</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my `app.component.html`, basically it is routing to my home component:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and here's my `home.component.html`:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 100%; background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);">
  <div class="row" style="height:13%; background-color: rgba(136, 255, 0, 0.1)">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-header></app-header>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="height:77%;">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="height:100%; background-color: rgba(255, 0, 179, 0.1)">
      <app-sidemenu></app-sidemenu>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10" style="height:100%; background-color: rgba(170, 48, 58, 0.1)">
      <app-cashplanner></app-cashplanner>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="height:10%; background-color: rgba(16, 16, 212, 0.1)">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The data I'm trying to show is in the `<app-cashplanner>` component.
and the `cashplanner.component.html` looks like this (you can imagine that there are hundreds of rows here:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table id="dt-material-checkbox" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th class="th-sm">Position
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Office
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Age
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Start date
          </th>
          <th class="th-sm">Salary
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name
          </th>
          <th>Position
          </th>
          <th>Office
          </th>
          <th>Age
          </th>
          <th>Start date
          </th>
          <th>Salaryzz
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

so the above table in my cashplanner leaked out of the container when it's open in the browser and my footer is not dynamically responsive to the table above it. Will eventually use pagination for the data but what I don't get is I thought the bootstrap classes are suppose to be dynamically adjusted to the browser as well and its parent/child div tags.

See image below, it went beyond..

[image: sample]

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a `table-responsive` class to a `div` containing the `table`.

Comment: the ```html``` and ```css``` for my ```footer``` component has almost nothing inside. ```footer.component.css``` is empty and ```footer.component.html``` has only ```<p> footer works! </p>``` and that's it. I was testing (that's why the files are almost empty) if the footer is sticky to the content above it but apparently it's not.